# Famo.us browser scroll emulation does not feel natural

Tags: scrollview, famo.us

I am creating a site in pure Famo.us, I wanted to have 1 page with sections where the user has possibility either click on links and scroll to anchors or scroll sequentially to get to sections. I used initially famo.us scrollview, but its behavior was not was not similar to browser scroll - I tried many options. I implemented my own scroll with Scrollsync, modifier and transition but it still does not feel similar to browser scroll. But the main problem that on Laptop and Desktop PC - I need to set different scrollscale to function normally. Here is the app:
    https://svet15.herokuapp.com/

Can anybody give a direction to solve the problem with syncscale and maybe how to make scroll similar to browser native scroll.

P.S. I keep mobile view separately from desktop, so window.width should be more than 500 to see the desktop view where I have this problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have no experience with `ScrollView`, but `FlexScrollView` from the `famous-flex` feels very natural to me on my desktop browser. https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-flex

Comment: thank you so much. It does work much better with surfaces and mouse scroll - I have some issues with Google maps, but I am sure I will figure out the problem. THANK YOU, MOTI!